# How to set style class to another class depends on selector?

Tags: html, css

So I have CSS style

```
.style-a {

}

.style-b {

}
```

And now I want to make my element to have difference styles when hovering or out. Psudo like:

```
.my-class {
  .style-a here
}

.my-class:hover {
  .style-b here
}
```

I cannot change the `style-a` and `style-b` because many other elements are dependent on those two and it will be bothering to change them. How can I achieve this functionality without change `style-a` and `style-b` and not using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.style-a`, and `.style-b` are both children of `.my-class`, you can use:

```
.my-class .style-a {
    // style here
}

.my-class:hover .style-b {
    // style here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create something like this:

```
.my-class {
  /*common elements here*/
}
.style-a {
 /*style-a elements*/
}
.style-b {
     /*style-b elements*/
}
.my-class .style-a {

}

.my-class .style-b {

}
```

I think this way you can set styles for the classes u need without needing to change them, and u set them as children classes

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in CSS.

But you can use [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) and compile a lesscss file into a CSS one.

It's called a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you've described with plain CSS. I can think of two options without Javascript:

1. Use the `@extend` feature of [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/#extend)
2. Copy and paste all the rules from `style-a` and `style-b`

Answer (score 0):

The @extend directive of Sass is what you are looking for:

The SCSS:

```
.style-a {
  // common styles
}

.style-b {
  // common styles
}

.my-class {
  @extend .style-a;
}

.my-class:hover {
  @extend .style-b;
}
```

The CSS:

```
.style-a, .my-class {
  // common styles
}

.style-b, .my-class:hover {
  // common styles
}
```

There is no other solution without JS and without copy/pasting, adding additional classes to your markup, or modifying the original styles to add an additional selector.